# For $n∈ N$, determine the real part of $(1 + i\sqrt{3})^{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

For $n∈ N$, determine the real part of $(1 + i\sqrt{3})^{n}$.

I just can't find the regularity within it. Thanks.

Comment: I am a little confused by your formula. Is it "one plus i times square root of 3" in the parentheses?

Comment: @Code-Guru - this is how I read it too

Comment: Regularities will come quickly if you compute. Maybe powers of $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ will be more familiar.

Answer (score 10):

**Hint:** Consider polar representation

Answer (score 1):

Use [De Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)
\begin{align}
\left[ 1+i\cdot \sqrt{3} \right]^n = 
&
2^n \left[ \frac{1}{2}+i\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right]^n
&
\\
=
&
2^n\cdot \left[\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+i\cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) \right]^n
&
\\
=
&
2^n\cdot \left[\cos\left(n\cdot\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+i\cdot \sin\left(n\cdot\frac{\pi}{3}\right) \right]
&   
\\
\end{align}
Let's $n= 3\cdot [2\cdot k]+r$. We have $r\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and
\begin{align}
\left[ 1+i\cdot \sqrt{3} \right]^n = 
&
2^n\cdot \left[\cos\left(r\cdot\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+i\cdot \sin\left(r\cdot\frac{\pi}{3}\right) \right]
\\
\end{align}
Then we have,
$$
Re\Big(\left[ 1+i\cdot \sqrt{3} \right]^{3(2k)+r}\Big)=
\begin{cases}
2^n\cdot \left(+\frac{1}{1} \right) & \mbox{ if } r=0 \\
2^n\cdot \left(+\frac{1}{2} \right) & \mbox{ if } r=1,5 \\
2^n\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{2} \right) & \mbox{ if } r=2,4 \\
2^n\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{1} \right) & \mbox{ if } r=3 \\
\end{cases}
$$